# Using string interpolation to append element in a multi line string under a for loop

Tags: python, string, list, file, string-interpolation

I'm having a multiline string which is going to be python file that needs to be generated:

```
for data in some_list:
       my_multline = """

       from my_module import something
       from my_module2 import something2

       my_list = [ %s ]
       """ % (data)

        file.write(my_multiline)
```

I can't directly represent my list on the my_list string interpolation, because the data inside "some_list" will work only if I add on the flow of iteration or else. The entire list will be represented as a plain string.

Expected output :
         from my_module import something
         from my_module2 import something2

```
     my_list = [ non_string_iterated_data1,
                 non_string_iterated_data2,
                 non_string_iterated_data3
                ]
```

What am getting currently is :

```
    from my_module import something
    from my_module2 import something2

    my_list = [ non_string_iterated_data3 ] # appending only the last element
```

If I refer the entire list then the output am getting is:

```
    from my_module import something
    from my_module2 import something2


    my_list = [ "string_data_1", "string_data_2", "string_data_3" ]
```

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: Please explain it using an example, expected output etc

Comment: @sau I've edited by adding expected output and the output am getting.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.format`

```
my_list = [ 10,11,12]
my_multline = """

       from my_module import something
       from my_module2 import something2

       my_list = {}
       """.format(my_list)
```